# Javascript - Pass a function with arguments as an argument

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

I'm cleaning up some script errors and have a delicate dilemma.

Consider this line of code:

```
Session.Timer = window.setTimeout("TimeoutHandler(Session)", 1000);
```

This will not work because when the Timeout tries to execute `TimeoutHandler(Session)` it will not know what the Session variable is (out of scope).

Is there a way to get the `Session` "value" translated to a *string* or *number* so it will be executed correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a closure (using an anonymous function) instead of a string, it will keep a reference to Session for you.

```
Session.Timer = window.setTimeout(function() { TimeoutHandler(Session); }, 1000);
```

If you're unfamiliar with closures, here's a [brief introduction](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

Comment: +1, but *closure **or** anonymous function* makes it sound like they are the same thing.

Comment: @alex Can't quite find wording I like for that, but for basic purposes anonymous functions and closures are closely enough related.

Comment: so obvious when I quick read the article :) I didn't know they kept the local variables even of scope. I learned something new! I could even implement the first solution I had in mind from the beginning :D